# How to make a line wrap in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a small data tooltip on my website so whenever someone hovers the word `Gig` the data tooltip appears. I'm using `::after` pseudo-element for it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-tool-tip="Products are called as 'Gigs' on Fiverr">Gigs</a>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
a[data-tool-tip] {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a[data-tool-tip]::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tool-tip);
  display: block;
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Playfair Display;
  padding: 1em 3em;
  font-size: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;

  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

The result coming out has a lot of line breaks. It is showing as below:

```
Products
are
called
as Gigs
on Fiverr
```

When I use `white-space: no-wrap;` then it whole becomes one line.

I WANT IT TO BE IN 2 LINES.

What Should I Do?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing just one posibility is to had a fixed width to the `::after` element like this :

```
a[data-tool-tip] {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
  }

  a[data-tool-tip]:hover::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    content: attr(data-tool-tip);
    display: block;
    background-color: #343a40;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Playfair Display;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;

    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
```

I put the width to 80px to be on 2 lines

But I don't unterstand why the`white-space: nowrap` haven't work on your side (it will be one line with it unless you add a `max-width` size on it and use `white-space: pre-wrap`)

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to set the width of the tooltip-elements or use a different approach.

```css
a[data-tool-tip] {
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
  font-size: 200%;
}

a[data-tool-tip]:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tool-tip);
  display: block;
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  min-width: 10em;

  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-tool-tip="Products are called as 'Gigs' on Fiverr">Gigs</a>
```